# Folders and files being duplicated in Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I have two main laptops, and have been using Dropbox to share files between them. Over time, I make changes to some of those files and folders, mostly through Windows File Manager. For example, if I rename a folder, it seems as if the old folder name does not really go away, and I end up with duplicates of all the content.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this basically what Dropbox does? How can I use it so that I don't end up with this proliferation of duplicate files, please?

Comment: You may just need to move the items outside the Dropbox folder, rename them and then re-add them. That way Dropbox hopefully will have a clear idea that the old items no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it. I wish that there was a solid definition of "sync" so I don't have to play guessing games. The other problem is how to clean the directory structure I now have, with hundreds of duplicated files. And to do it in a way that Dropbox doesn't later sabotage (although I am thinking of abandoning Dropbox because of this issue anyway).

Comment: You're welcome. I do have to agree that clearer syncing options would be a benefit, rather than just letting Dropbox handle it. You could probably use some normal file de-duping/comparison tools to get of the extras you have now. But doing it in a way Dropbox doesn't muck up later does seem relevant.

Comment: If this was a real issue, others would be posting this question too. But they are not. So what am I doing wrong...?

Comment: At a guess, since I can't say what your workflow is like, I am imagining that you have items that are simply out of sync. To me, it sounds as if changes on PC 1 are not being fully mirrored to PC 2 before additional changes are being made (adding/removing files, altering folder names, etc). Another possibility might  be that you are automatically backing content to your Dropbox and there is some other program that is inadvertently creating duplicate files (i.e. it is creating a new set of files, rather than updating the old ones in place). So Dropbox is syncing both versions.